# C++ priority_queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am looking how to build a heap in `O(n)` time and I found it using `Heapify`. But I wonder whether the `STL priority_queue` do the same? So my question is:

Which method of build heap is used by `priority_queue` available in STL?
Is it using the heapify which can turn the whole array to heap in `O(n)` or using one by one insertion of elements in heap taking `O(n log n)` time?

I am guessing it to be 2nd method as we manually insert elements one by one when using STL `priority_queue`. Am I correct?

Comment: There is [std::make_heap(...)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap), which accepts whole N-range at once to build heap. And as said in standard it has `O(N)` complexity.

Comment: The second method won't be `O(N)` in general, `make_heap` needs to be smarter than that to achive `O(N)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [std::make_heap(...)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap), which accepts whole N-range at once to build heap.

And as said in standard it has `O(N)` complexity. For example you can see how CLang implements std::make_heap, [source is here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/85167fb7c2920ca8874b197ef397e8e6b9d87c73/libcxx/include/algorithm#L5104).

Later you can use [std::push_heap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap) and [std::pop_heap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap) for adding and taking-out 1 by 1 element if needed in `O(log N)` time.

Also as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66780137/c-priority-queue/#comment118047363_66780185) by @Jarod42 you can use just [std::priority_queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue), because one of its constructors accepts range (iterators) with N elements, this constructor has `O(N)` complexity too.

Comment: And [std::priority_queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) uses `std::make_heap` when providing a range.

Comment: Thank you @Arty. So we can achieve it in O(N) but I still wonder if it uses heapify or something else for O(N)

Comment: @RitikaGupta In standard page it doesn't specify algorithm. It means that each compiler and platform is free to choose its own implementation as far as it is `O(N)`. It can appear that some or even all compilers use heapify.

Comment: @RitikaGupta For example you can see how CLang implements it, [source is here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/85167fb7c2920ca8874b197ef397e8e6b9d87c73/libcxx/include/algorithm#L5104).

Comment: @Arty Thanks a lot.